# Wrong Python module should throw appropriate error

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime, psutil

I am using the Python module psutil, where I am using the psutil dummy module in the code. For example,

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2016, 21:01:49)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensor()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sensor'
```

I want output like below changes

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2016, 21:01:49)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensor()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sensor'
RuntimeError: Unsupported function Sensor()   >>> looking for this output
```

What changes should I want to change in psutil modules to get that output?

Comment: _"What changes should I want to change in psutil modules to get that output ?"_ None. You shouldn't make any changes, and you shouldn't even want to make any changes. An AttributeError is 100% appropriate in this situation. Why would you ever want to throw a RuntimeError because of a missing attribute? This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I don't want to support few psutil module in my case. If someone use the module which is not supported  it should throw exception as unsupported function __funcname__()

Comment: Are you writing a wrapper for the `psutil` module? If so, throw your own exceptions instead of trying to change `psutil`'s exceptions. Or maybe you're writing a user interface for `psutil`? Either way, throw your own errors if someone tries to use your module incorrectly. And don't tamper with the `psutil` module. You gain nothing from making it throw different exceptions.